# export grid to excel in asp.net when the grid in ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export

i am trying to export a gridview data to excel. that grid is in a ContentPlaceHolder. that page has a master page.. when i press "export to excel" button its giving error as "**Control 'ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server**". but when i added a form tag in ContentPlaceHolder.. its giving error as "**A page can have only one server-side Form tag.**". in my master page one form tag is there. in this case how can i export grid data... Thanks **Cs code:---**

`protected void btnExoprtExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    Page.EnableViewState = false;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Report.xls");
    System.IO.StringWriter tw1 = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw1);
    trGV.RenderControl(hw1);
    //Response.Write("<b style='color:Green;font-size:19px;padding-left:100px;'>Report taken on " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "</b>\n\n");
    Response.Write(tw1.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

`..  **aspx code:--**`....

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CallbackPanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
         <table>
             <tr id="trGV" runat="server">
             <td>
              <asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ></asp:GridView>
             </td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
          <td align="right" >           
                <asp:Button ID="btnExoprtExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" 
                    onclick="btnExoprtExcel_Click" />
          </td>
        </tr>       
         </table>        
        </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
    </asp:Content>
```

.......`-------> i tried by adding`

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```

` in cs page. and removed "asp:form" tag in ContentPlaceHolder tag . but when i run the application in debug mode i am getting error as " **RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();** "

-------> i tried by modifying the code as `

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
         <table>
             <tr id="trGV" runat="server">
             <td>
              <asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ></asp:GridView>
             </td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
          <td align="right" >           
                <asp:Button ID="btnExoprtExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" 
                    onclick="btnExoprtExcel_Click" />
          </td>
        </tr>       
         </table>
    </asp:Content>
```

` by removing form tag and updatepanel. but still giving error at debug point as " **RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();** " can any one suggest other solution.

Issue is solved by using "EnableEventValidation="false"" in <%@ Page location. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove form tag from your master page and place it in content page as

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
// your html markup
</form></asp:Content>
```

You can place only one form tag either place it in master page or in content page. but if you place it in content page you have to do it with every content page
Edit :RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render(); to solve this error mjust add  EnableEventValidation="false" to @Page directive to master page directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ExportGridviewtoExcel.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExportGridviewtoExcel" EnableEventValidation="false"%>
```

Comment: First thanks for your answer. i tried your solution, but i have a ScriptManager in my master page. while executing code its giving error as " Control 'ScriptManager1' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. "   is there any other solution for this issue.. thanks

Comment: try to keep form tag in master page and removing update panel from content page i tried it without update panel and it works

Comment: Don't close your form tag before </contentplaceholder>

Comment: i tried but still giving error as "RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();"  can you suggest other solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your .cs page
Add this namespace

```
   using System.IO;
   public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}



protected void btnExoprtExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Details.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GV1.AllowPaging = false;
    //Change the Header Row back to white color
    GV1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#000000");
    //Applying stlye to gridview header cells
    for (int i = 0; i < GV1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        GV1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#000000");
    }
    int j = 1;
    //This loop is used to apply stlye to cells based on particular row
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GV1.Rows)
    {

        if (j <= GV1.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
                }
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
    GV1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

This made my gridview export to excel,It may help you

Comment: I tried this by removing <form> tag in "ContentPlaceHolder". but its giving error at debug stage as " RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render(); "

Comment: Is `<asp:UpdatePanel>`  necessary for you?

Comment: Remove `<form>,<asp:UpdatePanel> and <ContentTemplate>`,it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the given below code. This is an simplest example for exporting gridview data to word and excel format. Thank you.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string str = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["work2ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string com = "Select * from details";
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "sName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "sId";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from details where sId = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        Adpt.Fill(ds, "details");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }
    private void ExportGrid(string fileName, string contentType)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;fileName=" + fileName);
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = contentType;

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportGrid("GridviewData.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportGrid("GridViewData.doc", "application/vnd.ms-word");
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
}
```